# invalid input syntax for type boolean in if condition

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create the following function in Postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emat_proc_ad_user_login(user_id_in character varying, password_in character varying)
      RETURNS character varying AS
    $BODY$
    declare
        TESTING character varying(200):='';
    BEGIN
        raise notice 'before if case';

        IF (USER_ID_IN is NULL AND PASSWORD_IN IS NULL) THEN
            TESTING:='Username Or Password Cannot Be Blank';
            RAISE NOTICE '%',TESTING;

        ELSIF (SELECT USER_ID  FROM AD_USERMASTER WHERE USER_ID=USER_ID_IN) THEN
            IF (SELECT USER_ID  FROM AD_USERMASTER WHERE password=password_in) THEN
                TESTING:=USER_ID_IN;
                RAISE NOTICE '%',TESTING;
            ELSE
                TESTING:='PASSWORD INCORRECT';
            END IF;
        ELSE 
            IF (SELECT USER_ID FROM AD_USERMASTER WHERE password=password_in) THEN
                TESTING:='USER ID INCORRECT';
                RAISE NOTICE '%',TESTING;
            ELSE  
                raise notice 'first else part';
                TESTING:='USER ID AND PASSWORD INCORRECT';
                RAISE NOTICE '%',TESTING;
            END IF;
        END IF;

    return TESTING;

    END;
    $BODY$
```

while run this script in postgresql it shows an error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "sadmin"
```

> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function emat_proc_ad_user_login(character
>   varying,character varying) line 7 at IF

Comment: could you send what set of parameters make your function crash

Comment: SELECT emat_proc_ad_user_login(
    
    'sadmin','admin'
);         and                                                                                   SELECT emat_proc_ad_user_login(
    
    'sjh','sdnj'
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the line containing `ELSIF`.

`IF` or `ELSIF` expect a boolean expression, but field `user_id` from table `ad_usermaster` seems to be a string data type. PostgreSQL tries to cast the query result to a boolean and fails because the value `sadmin` is not a valid boolean.

The correct solution depends on what you are trying to achieve, but maybe it is something along these lines:

```
ELSIF EXISTS
   (SELECT user_id FROM ad_usermaster WHERE user_id = user_id_in)
THEN
```

Comment: Thanks for reply immediately for my query and solution you mentioned, its working fine.